# Как подключится к twitch.tv

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

Мне необходимо написать программу, которая бы показывала пользователей канала и по необходимости переключиться на стрим канала.

Я попробовал код из урока, однако у меня нет доступа к API.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
var url ="https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/freecodecamp";
$.getJSON(url,function(data1){

});
})
```

Данный url подключения не работает, так как видимо ему нужен какой-то номер пользователя. Мне хотелось бы знать, как его получить.
Даже при стандартном запросе бяка:

```
     curl -i https://api.twitch.tv/kraken
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: 
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: 
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Age: 0
Cache-Control: max-age=0, private, must-revalidate
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 07 Dec 2016 16:00:20 GMT
Server: nginx
Status: 400 Bad Request
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Via: 1.1 varnish
X-API-Version: 3
X-MH-Cache: rails-varnish-api-aws-0ae1f1a3c7c2916de; M
X-Request-Id: 7c566325f3f52de40f2625c1d083af60
X-UA-Compatible: IE=Edge,chrome=1
X-Varnish: 713591920
Content-Length: 71
Connection: keep-alive

{"error":"Bad Request","status":400,"message":"No client id specified"}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать `twitch-js-sdk` ([ссылка](https://github.com/justintv/twitch-js-sdk)).

Пример работы:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ttv-api.s3.amazonaws.com/twitch.min.js"></script>

<script>
  Twitch.init({clientId: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID_HERE'}, function(error, status) {
    // the sdk is now loaded
  });
</script>
```